# IF statement with two conditions for the same variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to write an if sentence that checks if a variable accomplishes one of two given conditions.

What I was trying to evaluate is: "if the variable is bigger than 0 or the variable is equal to "more than one" then print its value.

Here's what I have:

```
$var="more than three";

if (($var == 'more than one') || ($var > '0'))  {
  echo "var is: " . $var;
}
// produces "var is more than three"

$var=0;

if (($var == 'more than one') || ($var > '0'))  {
  echo "var is: " . $var;
}
// produces "var is 0"
```

In both cases I'd expect no echo. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I meant "more than one" in the description to match the code.

Comment: what output you actually want?

Comment: when you say equal to 'more than one' do you mean literally the string 'more than one' or it's a number that is >1?

Comment: Yes, in the example I'm comparing the same variable over an integer value and a string.
With those values I'd expect no output at all because the variable does not match any of the two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use typecasting here because you're dealing with integer as well as string types for $var.

Try this:

```
$var = "more than three";

if (((string)$var == 'more than one') || ((int)$var > 0))  {
  echo "var is: " . $var;
} 

$var = 0;
if (((string)$var == 'more than one') || ((int)$var > 0))  {
   echo "var is: " . $var;
}
```

You could use this as a reference: [PHP Typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Comment: You're right, thanks! I was thinking php would compare types based on the type the variable was declared, so in my tests I didn't try to typecast 0 as an integer or "hello" as a string as they were already defined as integer and string respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Can u try this ?

```
if (($var == 'more than one') || ($var > 0))  {
  echo "var is: " . $var;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried it too but doesn't work. It only works if $var is a string.

Comment: The strange thing is that if you split in two if sentences (without typecasting) both of them work! It looks like php doesn't work well when you use two different types in one sentence.